# validate that for each cell value in one column only one unique combination of cells in the row exists

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new with VBA, but most of the searches I've come across have done the opposite and instead search to make sure no duplicates appear (like unique pass combinations).

Anyways, I have an excel sheet that tracks the retail prices (column C) for items (Column A) in a particular Area ID (column B) and essentially what we've had to filter through each Area ID (column B) and make sure that only one unique combination of ID (B) and retail price (C) exists for each ID.

So for example in the data below I'd look at column B, 200 and find that it has two unique combinations of B & C (200/2.19 and 200/2.29) which would flag as an error, 204 for example is correct since it has 204/2.19 and 204/2.19 as a result).

A   200  2.19

B   200  2.29

C   202  2.19

D   203  2.19

E   204  2.19

G   204  2.19

My question would be how would I set up a filter to only display the Area IDs that have errors (so in this example it would only display Rows A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were doing this by formula, you could add a column containing

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10,B2,C$2:C$10,"<>"&C2)
```

and test for this being non-zero.

In VBA you could do the same thing and put the Area ID's into an array where there is more than one price value

```
Sub Filter()
Dim arr As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
With Sheet1
    Cells.AutoFilter
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arr(LastRow)
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("b1:b" & LastRow), Cells(i, 2), Range("c1:c" & LastRow), "<>" & Cells(i, 3)) Then
            arr(i) = CStr(Cells(i, 2))
        End If
    Next i
    Range("A1").AutoFilter _
        Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=arr, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
End Sub
```